# SoapUI integration with bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, soapui, bamboo

can anyone share a link/info - how to integrate SoapUI test-suites with Bamboo? I'm interested both in local and "from SVN" integration. And I need to know - must I install SoapUI somewhere else for integration with CI, or not? (jobs on CI should work independently)

Google gave me some info, but I did not find some answers...

Thank You!

Comment: There is this: http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Solution:
POM-plan in Bamboo-correct dependencies. For jms I used "geronimo"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```